# Aggregating PySpark DataFrame interpreting NULL values as wildcards

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am grouping a DataFrame by 5 columns, if any one of them is `NULL`, I want to ignore that and group by remaining 4 columns for that row and calculate the desired aggregate function on column for that group.

I am writing it in SnowPark.

I have a DataFrame like this:

| colA | colB | colC | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BI | 2 | c | 2 |
| MO | 3 | c | 4 |
| NULL | 2 | c | 9 |
| BI | 2 | c | 2 |
| MO | 2 | c | 4 |
| MO | 3 | c | 2 |
| MO | NULL | d | 4 |
| MO | 3 | d | 2 |
| MO | 2 | d | 3 |

And I want it grouped like this:

| A | B | C | Amount_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BI | 2 | c | 4 |
| MO | 3 | c | 6 |
| NULL | 2 | c | 17 |
| MO | 2 | c | 4 |
| MO | NULL | d | 9 |
| MO | 3 | d | 2 |
| MO | 2 | d | 3 |

Whenever there is `NULL` value for a column I want to ignore that column and perform group by on remaining ones.

**As suggested in snowflake snowpark i am trying to do**

Hi think there is problem in my code then in snowflake snowpark i am  doing

```
df=df_b=session.create_dataframe([
      ("BI", 2,    "c", 2),
      ("MO", 3,    "c", 4),
      (None, 2,    "c", 9),
      ("BI", 2,    "c", 2),
      ("MO", 2,    "c", 4),
      ("MO", 3,    "c", 2),
      ("MO", None, "d", 4),
      ("MO", 3,    "d", 2),
      ("MO", 2,    "d", 3)],
      schema=["a", "b", "c", "amount"]
    )



joinExpr = (
    (F.when(df.A.isNull(), F.lit(True)).otherwise(df.A == df_b.A)) &
    (F.when(df.B.isNull(), F.lit(True)).otherwise(df.B == df_b.B)) &
    (F.when(df.C.isNull(), F.lit(True)).otherwise(df.C == df_b.C)))
result = (
    df.select("A", "B", "C").distinct()\
    .join(df_b, joinExpr)\
    .groupBy(df.A, df.B, df.C)\
    .agg(F.avg(df.amount).alias("Amount_sum"))
)
print(result.show())`
```

but getting result as

| r_ia4e_A | r_ia4e_B | r_ia4e_C | AMOUNT_SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BI | 2 | c | 2.000000 |
| MO | 3 | c | 3.000000 |
| NULL | 2 | c | 9.000000 |
| MO | 2 | c | 4.000000 |
| MO | NULL | d | 4.000000 |
| MO | 3 | d | 2.000000 |
| MO | 2 | d | 3.000000 |

Comment: Please provide a sample input and output example appropriately formatted.

Comment: @user238607 i have provided sample input and output.

Comment: You can't choose to ignore one column in a group by dynamically.   Additionally, your desired result doesn't match.  Add up amount_sum in your sample you get 32, in your desired result you get 45.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("BI", 2,    "c", 2),
  ("MO", 3,    "c", 4),
  (None, 2,    "c", 9),
  ("BI", 2,    "c", 2),
  ("MO", 2,    "c", 4),
  ("MO", 3,    "c", 2),
  ("MO", None, "d", 4),
  ("MO", 3,    "d", 2),
  ("MO", 2,    "d", 3)],
  schema=["a", "b", "c", "amount"]
)

joinExpr = F.expr(
    "IF(A.a IS NULL, TRUE, A.a = B.a) AND "
    "IF(A.b IS NULL, TRUE, A.b = B.b) AND "
    "IF(A.c IS NULL, TRUE, A.c = B.c)"
)

df.alias("A").select("a", "b", "c").distinct() \
  .join(df.alias("B"), joinExpr) \
  .groupBy("A.a", "A.b", "A.c").sum("B.amount") \
  .show(100)
```

```
+----+----+---+-----------+
|   a|   b|  c|sum(amount)|
+----+----+---+-----------+
|  MO|   3|  c|          6|
|  BI|   2|  c|          4|
|null|   2|  c|         17|
|  MO|null|  d|          9|
|  MO|   3|  d|          2|
|  MO|   2|  c|          4|
|  MO|   2|  d|          3|
+----+----+---+-----------+
```

A single aggregation is not enought, you need to do a join. And in the join, when the value is `NULL`, return `TRUE`.

#### About the comment

I have added a new row (the last one) to test the example `(a=null, b=2, c=null)`:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("BI", 2,    "c", 2),
  ("MO", 3,    "c", 4),
  (None, 2,    "c", 9),
  ("BI", 2,    "c", 2),
  ("MO", 2,    "c", 4),
  ("MO", 3,    "c", 2),
  ("MO", None, "d", 4),
  ("MO", 3,    "d", 2),
  ("MO", 2,    "d", 3),
  (None, 2,    None, 2),],
  schema=["A", "B", "C", "amount"]
)

joinExpr = F.expr(
    "IF(A.a IS NULL, TRUE, A.a = B.a) AND "
    "IF(A.b IS NULL, TRUE, A.b = B.b) AND "
    "IF(A.c IS NULL, TRUE, A.c = B.c)"
)

df.alias("A").select("a", "b", "c").distinct() \
  .join(df.alias("B"), joinExpr) \
  .groupBy("A.a", "A.b", "A.c").sum("B.amount") \
  .show(100)
```

```
+----+----+----+-----------+
|   a|   b|   c|sum(amount)|
+----+----+----+-----------+
|  MO|   3|   c|          6|
|  BI|   2|   c|          4|
|null|   2|   c|         17|
|null|   2|null|         22| <--- This one
|  MO|   2|   c|          4|
|  MO|null|   d|          9|
|  MO|   3|   d|          2|
|  MO|   2|   d|          3|
+----+----+----+-----------+`
```

Let's see that it's the same result (22):

```py
df.createOrReplaceTempView("mytable")
spark.sql("select sum(amount) from mytable where B=2").show()
```

```
+-----------+
|sum(amount)|
+-----------+
|         22|
+-----------+
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and suggestions. i am doing this on snowpark data frames in snowflake and there is nothing like df.alias

Comment: i tried following 

joinExpr = (
    (F.when(df.A.isNull(), F.lit(True)).otherwise(df.A == df_b.A)) &
    (F.when(df.B.isNull(), F.lit(True)).otherwise(df.B == df_b.B)) &
    (F.when(df.C.isNull(), F.lit(True)).otherwise(df.C == df_b.C)))
    result = (
    df.select("A", "B", "C").distinct()
    .join(df_b, joinExpr)
    .groupBy(df.A, df.B, df.C)
    .agg(F.avg(df_b.amount).alias("Amount_AVG"))
)

but it is considering null values in group by agg

Comment: In [Snowpark API](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame) there is an `alias` function. With respect to your second comment, I have tested your `joinExpr` and it gives me the same result. What do you mean by `"but it is considering null values in group by agg"`? Could you share an example? Isn't that the expected behaviour?

Comment: 1.I think that alias is for columns if i try to do 

`df=df.alias("A")`

i am getting error  `in alias
    _copy._select_statement.df_aliased_col_name_to_real_col_name[name][
KeyError: 'A' `
2. and by considering nulls i mean if i have a row like 
`A: NULL , B:value , C: NULL ` then i want it to ignore null and perform agg on non null present column value. so  the agg result should be similar like 
`select sum(amount) from table where B='value'` as A and B are null. but in this case i am getting agg similar to `select sum(amount) from table where A is null and B='value' and c is null`

Comment: I get the same result in both cases. I think the result is actually what you want. I have added a section in the answer adding more details.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code which i am trying in snowpark. can u pls take a look at it. i think i am missing something, Thanks much :)

Comment: The code seems ok. I don't use `snowpark` so unfortunately I can't help you. One thing you can try is creating `df_b` this way `df_b = df.select("*")`. In `Spark` I get an error in the join if I do `df=df_b=session.create_...`.

Comment: i tried that but it is not working :( .. btw thanks for inputs